# Laravel Spark API Functionality

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-spark

I am new to laravel spark and I'm trying to figure out the built-in API functionality. I am trying to consume the API within my application but the permissions I am setting seem that are not functioning properly or I am doing something wrong.

This is my api.php

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function () {


    Route::get('/servers', function () {
        if (Auth::user()->token()->can('read-servers')) {
            return 'OK';
        }else{
            return 'Unauthorised';
        }   
    });


});
```

Which when I call through postman is working just fine and returns 'Unauthorised' but when I am calling it through my view it always returns 'OK'.

My home.js

```
Vue.component('home', {
    props: ['user'],

    ready() {
        //  
    },

    methods: {
        greet: function () {
            this.$http.get('/api/servers')
                .then(response=> {
                    alert(response.data)
            });   
        }
    }


});
```

Are my permissions being skipped just because I am calling the api within my app? Should I use an additional package such as spatie/laravel-permission to handle roles/permissions within the app? Is what I am trying to do even valid?

Comment: Have you tried to use axios?

Comment: No but I will. The api route was abandoned for now though.